Move cursor in assembly
I use this:
asm("mov ebx, xPos"
    "mov ecx, yPos")
    "mov eax, [GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("user32.dll"),"SetCoursorPos")]
    "call eax");

I want change mouse pointer in screen, I get "too many memory reference for mov" while building(WinOS).

What's the purpose of the qt tag?

Write in Qt5.14.1

Removed Qt tag as you do not seem to be interested in a Qt solution. Whether you are using Qt in other parts of your project is irrelevant for this question. This question seems to be focused on an assembly error message, which has nothing to do with qt.

What C compiler are you using? MSVC/C++? MinGW?GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("user32.dll"),"SetCoursorPos") is not a valid address. You will need to supply the address.

If this is supposed to be GNU C inline asm, you need to tell the compiler what inputs you read using Extended Asm syntax.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended).  And safely making a call from inside an asm statement is very complicated; you have to tell the compiler about all the call-clobbered registers including SSE and x87.  Direct C function call using GCC's inline assembly / Calling printf in extended inline ASM

Also, are you sure that function takes args in EBX and ECX?  That's the calling convention for 32-bit Linux kernel system calls; 32-bit Windows normally uses stdcall with args on the stack.
